# How to set context 'this' to custom object inside function?

Tags: jquery, this

Consider code like this:

```
external_function = function() {
    $(this).something2();
}

$('.someclass').live('click', function() {

    $(this).something1();
    external_function(); // wrong way

});
```

I can add a new method:

```
external_function = function() {
    $(this).something2();
}

$('.someclass').live('click', function() {

    $(this).something1();
    this.external_function = external_function;
    this.external_function(); // this will work

});
```

but it seems having overhead to me. Is there a perfect and safe way run external_function with custom context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read about `apply` and `call`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: Thanks. Well, I think jQuery.proxy (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) has the same functionality.